# How difficult is it for a US citizen to go back to the US with a non-resident spouse?

Tags: greencard, marriage

My fiancee is in the US legally on a non-immigrant visa.

She didn't know me before she came, she hasn't worked here, our relationship is bona fide, etc. So after we get married here in the US, she should qualify for Adjustment of Status and be able to stay while waiting for her green card.

But, we want to move abroad soon. We were planning to get married in a few months, and then travel for a while, eventually settling abroad.

However, after reading about the difficulties getting a non-citizen spouse into the US, I'm worried that if we change our minds and decide to come back to the US, we'll find ourselves stuck in limbo for a few years waiting for her to get a green card when she could have got it easily if we just stayed.

It even sounds like we would have a hard time just coming back to visit my family temporarily; it's not clear if as my wife she would even be able to get a non-immigrant visa again.

Our lease is up soon, we were excited to go abroad for while, but how difficult would it be for us to come back to live in the US, from a legal point of view? Would staying until she has a green card makes things easier in the future?

Comment: You have a lot of individual questions here that you're trying to wrap up into a single request for advice. Requests for advice aren't appropriate for this site, but you could probably get answers for each individual question. Unless they're very related, they'd be better as separate questions. And look around—I bet some have already been answered.

Comment: What kind of non-immigrant visa?

Comment: You have to do some work to maintain permanent residence status: http://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/maintaining-permanent-residence

Comment: I tried to make the question a bit more focused/less opinion-based, please let me know if that's OK.

Comment: "after reading about the difficulties getting a non-citizen spouse" - reading where? I know of several such couples and none had any difficulties whatsoever. It's just paperwork and a couple of months waiting. What difficulties are you anticipating and why?